# using $_POST with foreach loop

Tags: php

i'm trying to create a form to insert students marks in a college .. i have a list with all students id's and a form with marks .. this is my form :

```
<input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="{$student.id}" />
<input type="text" name="mark[]" size="5" />
```

of course the field is repeated in the form , but the problem is when i'm trying to print the results , this is my code

```
foreach ($_POST as $student){
            echo $student['id'].$student['mark'];
        }
```

but i get this when i submit the form :

Undefined index: id
Undefined index: mark

What's the problem with my code, PLZ ?

Comment: why don't you do a `var_dump` of your `$_POST` and see what the structure is you are looping over?

Comment: also no need for the hidden field, you can just do `<input type="text" name="mark[{$student.id}]" size="5" />`, much easier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `$student.id` is unique perhaps you should consider something like:

```
<input type="text" name="mark[{$student.id}]" size="5" />
```

This will give you a result in the php side similar to

```
Array
(
    [mark] => Array
        (
            [studentID1] => 14
            [studentID2] => 60
            [studentID3] => 89
        )

)
```

Therefore in the php you can do this:

```
foreach($_POST['mark'] as $studentID => $mark){
    echo "The student". $studentID ." achieved mark: ". $mark;
}
```

Comment: exactly my thought! +1

Comment: my respect, better answer

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($_POST['id'] as $key => $studentId){
    echo $student['id'][$key].$student['mark'][$key];
}
```

You are working on a Array when you are declaring name="id[]".
If you have two name"id[]" on form before post, it will be posted as:

```
array( 
    'id' => array(
         '0' => '',
         '1' => '',
     );
);
```

Then you should use

```
foreach ($array['id'] as $key => $value) {
    echo $array['id'][$key]; //got value
    echo $array['name'][$key]; //got custom value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given you form you want something like this:

```
foreach ($_POST['id'] as $key => $id){
     echo $id. $_POST['mark'][$key];
}
```